# Error ` saveas method workbook failed` in vba Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have basic data with multiple excels which i need to sorted out the data based on the columns whereas the sorted data which has a unique values and these uniques values i put in array ,based on unique values a new workbook has to be create.

My problem:

1. When im excuting the macro sometimes its showing the error as
           `saveas method workbook class failed`
2. How can i freeze a column?

My code:

```
sub marcel()
Dim sArray as string
Dim saArray as string
Dim Lastrow_Sub As Integer
Dim Lastrow_Aging As Integer
Dim Array_Sub As Variant
Dim Array_Sub_Aging As Variant
Dim rngFilter_Ws2 as range
Dim Sht6 as worksheet
Dim ColumnsToRemove2 as variant
Dim j2 as integer
Dim vItem2 as variant


Check_date = Format(Date, "yymm")

         Sheets("q_Aging_base_data_incl_FDB").Columns("D:D").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
         CopyToRange:=.Range("AY1"), Unique:=True
         Lastrow_Aging = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AY").End(xlUp).Row

         Array_Sub_Aging = Range("AY2:AY" & Lastrow_Aging)
         saArray = Array_Sub_Aging(m, 1)

            Sheets("BASE qry_Inventory Activation b").Columns("H:H").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=.Range("AZ1"), Unique:=True
            Lastrow_Sub = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp).Row

            Array_Sub = Range("AZ2:AZ" & Lastrow_Sub)
            sArray = Array_Sub(k, 1)

If sArray <> "APE" And saArray = "APE" Or sArray <> "XXUMA" And saArray = "XXUMA" Then

                  Dim NewBook_Sub_Aging As Workbook
                  Set NewBook_Sub_Aging = Workbooks.Add

                  With NewBook_Sub_Aging

                        .Title = saArray
                        NewBook_Sub_Aging.Worksheets("sheet1").Name = "Aging Inventory"

                        With rngFilter_Ws2

                            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=saArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                            .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="reporting relevant Location", Operator:=xlFilterValues
                            .AutoFilter Field:=32, Criteria1:="<>(a)  0 - 360", Operator:=xlFilterValues

                            Set rngCopyAging_Sub = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                                                   .AutoFilter ' Switch off AutoFilter

                        End With

                        rngCopyAging_Sub.Copy Destination:=NewBook_Sub_Aging.Worksheets("Aging Inventory").Cells(1, 1)

                         ' Delete unwanted columns for subregions(APE and XXUMA) Aging

                         Set Sht6 = NewBook_Sub_Aging.Worksheets("Aging Inventory")

                          ColumnsToRemove2 = Array("Period", "AP_BU", "Subregion", "Strategic_BU", "Company_Code", "Company_name", "Plant_name", _
                                            "Rep Location", "Storage_Location", "Storage_Location_name", "Date_last_goods_rec", "Stock_type", _
                                            "Stock_type_name", "Kind_of_Material_name", "Supplier_name", "SummevonVEU_OIV1", "Days_since_production", _
                                            "Remaining_shelf_life", "APO_Planner", "S_SCM_or_SVC")

                          For j2 = LBound(ColumnsToRemove2) To UBound(ColumnsToRemove2) Step 1
                                vItem6 = Application.Match(ColumnsToRemove2(j2), Sht6.Rows(1), 0)
                                Debug.Print vItem6
                            If IsNumeric(vItem6) Then
                                Sht6.Columns(vItem6).Delete
                             End If
                          Next j2

                                NewBook_Sub_Aging.Worksheets("Aging Inventory").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                                NewBook_Sub_Aging.Worksheets("Aging Inventory").Range("A1:P1").AutoFilter
                                NewBook_Sub_Aging.Worksheets("Aging Inventory").Range("A2:P2").Select
                                ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True


                        .SaveAs Filename:="KPI" & " " & saArray & " " & Check_date & ".xlsx"
                        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

                  NewBook_Sub_Aging.Close
                  End With

             End If
end sub
```

can anyone please help me out how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Should there be `sArray` and `saArray` variables?  Is this line correct: `sArray <> "APE" And saArray = "APE" Or sArray <> "XXUMA" And saArray = "XXUMA"` or should it be `(sArray <> "APE" And saArray = "APE") Or (sArray <> "XXUMA" And saArray = "XXUMA)"`?  What's the value held in `saArray` and `Check_date`?  Is `saArray` an array of values that you're using in the filename?

Comment: I assume by the name `check_date` is a date and may contain forward slashes. File names cannot hold the following characters:   \ / : * ? " < > |

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook sArray and saArray contains string variables.ex APE,APED,APEA etc `sArray <> "APE" And saArray = "APE" Or sArray <> "XXUMA" And saArray = "XXUMA"``is correct line. `Check_date` holds the current month . saArray is not the value its a string. the filename has to create like this `KPI APE 1604.xlsx`

Comment: @LiamH I haven't add any of these characters \ / : * ? " < > | in the filename

Comment: @buddhasreekanth I assumed that `check_date` was a date value as the name suggests; not just a month string.

Comment: So, sArray and saArray contain a single string value (best declare them as strings rather than variants).  What is an example value of `"KPI" & " " & saArray & " " & Check_date & ".xlsx"` when it throws the error?  (copy the line into the immediate window preceded by a `?`).

Comment: I do not see `saArray` or `Check_date` declared in the code you provided.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook sorry I have declared the `sArray` and `saArray` as a string. The example is `KPI APE 1604.xlsx`. `sArray` holds the strings like `APED,APEA,APES,APEU` and  `saArray` hols the same strings with two more string values `APED,APEA,APES,APEU,APE,XXUMA`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook it throws error when `saArray` is `APE` and `XXUMA`.

Comment: @IronMan could you please check the code once again.

Answer (score 0):

Both sArray and saArray don't seem to be defined as an actual array. Arrays are defined like this:

```
Dim myArray() as Integer
```

Any value assigned to any of the array positions need to be put in this way:

```
myArray(i) = 815 'i being a position, like 0 or 5
```

When you want to get the value held in a certain position, you would also reference that position. So, if I wanted the value in the 4th position of may array, I'd do

```
myArray(3) 'Arrays are zero-index based.
```

so when you do:

```
.SaveAs Filename:="KPI" & " " & saArray & " " & Check_date & ".xlsx"
```

You're giving the Filename parameter a variant variable that may contain nothing, so the line would throw an error.

I'll assume saArray and Check_date are global variables coming from a different Sub and the array is created and its values assigned over there; it would still throw an error, since you're giving the SaveAs module an array, and not a string. You HAVE to give it one of the values IN the array (And it has to be a string, since Filename has to be a string).

Comment: sArray and saArray contains string variables.ex `APE,APED,APEA` etc . Check_date` holds the current month . saArray is not the value its a string. the filename has to create like this `KPI APE 1604.xlsx`